# Unhandled promise rejection: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .addField("DJ", `https://discord.gg/microsoft`)
    .addField("Unchecked`)
    .setColor("#363940")
    .setTimestamp();
        
msg.author.send(embed);     

let xd = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor("#ff0000")
    .setTitle("CHECK YOUR DM")
    .setThumbnail("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/773133136929226763/797204521997828106/777514274829893683.gif")
    .setFooter("DJ")
    .setTimestamp()
    .setDescription("I've sent you")

msg.reply(xd).then(m => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        m.delete();
    }, 900000);
});

cooldown.add(msg.author.id);
setTimeout(() => {
    cooldown.delete(msg.author.id);
}, config.COOLDOWN * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: Probably unrelated but your code has a pair of mismatched quotes in the second `.addField`

Answer (score 0):

about "cannot send message to this user":

It could happen due to some reasons;

• The user doesn't share a server with the bot,

• The user has dms closed,

• The user has the bot blocked.

So you'll need to handle the error by putting `.catch(console.error)` or `.catch((e) => {//Function here})`

To fix it, replace the `msg.author.send(embed)` with the following:

```
msg.author.send(embed).catch(console.error)
```

---

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and how to make a command only usable on the channel you specify?

Comment: @DJ18,  There's two ways

1: Put `if (!message.channel.id === '// Channel ID For the command to work on') return;`
This way will Trigger `return` if the channel of the message is not the one you specified.
2: Put your code block inside the channel filter: `if (message.chnanel.id === '//Channel-id') {
// Your command's code
}`